# FB send button inside backbone view not loading

Tags: backbone.js

I have a FB send button inside one of my views.

I looked around and there is a question on SO that says to use `FB.XML.parse();` to re-render all the buttons on the page.

I tried putting that in my render function, but still no luck:

```
render: function() {
      var created_at = this.model.pretty_created_at();
      var share_url = this.model.share_url();
      var html = this.template({model:this.model.toJSON(), created_at: created_at, share_url: share_url});
      Galleria.configure({
          initialTransition: false,
          clicknext: true,
      });
      Galleria.run('#galleria', {wait: true});
      $(this.el).html(html);
      this.$('abbr.timeago').timeago();
      FB.XML.parse();
      return this;
},
```

Also, please comment on my render function, should I move some of this stuff into initialize?

Answer (score 0):

If it does not throw errors like 'FB is undefined', which may be happening if your script executes before 'FB' is loaded -- than you might be calling wrong script, or calling it before Like button placeholders are inserted into DOM.

On this page http://www.vitalmtb.com FB like buttons are created asyncronously and are parsed using `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("sp-a"));` and it works.